# How would you calculate expected value of sales leads?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Simplified situation:

- I have 1000 leads, but can only pursue 100 of them due to limited
  resources (salespeople).
- Each of these leads can be pitched up to N products, each with its
  own dollar value and estimated probability to convert.
- Not all customers have all N products available to them, they might
  only qualify for n/N of them.
- A customer can convert on any combination of those n products.

How to calculate the expected value of the leads, so that I can prioritize the top 100? If it were a single product I could just multiply dollar value by probability to convert, but how do I account for multiple products that can be pitched to the lead?

Comment: This is far too vague.  Obviously the exact specifications matter.If you have all the details on a given lead (and the available customer base) then you should be able to determine the expected value of any given lead.  If you don't have all those details, then you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the cost of each product and the probability that the lead will convert for each product, then you can calculate the "expected" amount of money you will make on each lead. Basically, multiply the cost of the product by the probability they will buy it, and repeat for all products adding it together. Here's a formula:

$$\hat y= \sum_{i=0}^n P(i)\text{ }C(i)$$

Here: $\hat y = $ expected sales, $i=$ each product,  $P(i) = $ the probability they will buy the product and $C(i) = $ the cost of the product. It gets more complicated when you want to calculate risk using standard deviation. Also if you do not have all the parts in the summation, you can't exactly predict the expected sales.

Comment: Can I just sum up the expected value of each product like that? Shouldn't I also consider the joint probability of selling multiple products on the same sales call?

Comment: @tiptop007 This formula just finds the expected amount you'd make for each product like you would if you were selling just 1 product, and adds them together. This is definitely a valid way to do it, as long as you know all the probabilities for each person. Think of it like reaching in a bag of coins where $2/3$ of the coins are $\$1$ and the other $1/3$ coins are $\$10$. On average how much would you make? You'd make $\$2/3 + \$10/3$ or $\$4$. Look at my formula and it's doing the same thing. Also if you drew 2 coins you'd expect to make $\$8$.